# Norm for adjoint action and relation to norm of matrix?

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras, operator-algebras

Consider an operator or matrix $O$ the adjoint action then is $ad_O M=[O,M]$, where $M$ is an arbitrary test matrix.

My question as follows:
Is there a norm that has been defined for $ad_O$ and if so how does it relate to the operator norm of $O$? Take the Frobenius norm specificially $norm(O)=\sqrt{OO^\dagger}$. What norm for $ad_O$ is there that relates the easiest to this norm if any?

Pleas note that specificically I am looking for a relation of the form
$$\left\lVert ad_O\right\rVert_{1}=f(\left\lVert g_1(O)\right\rVert,...,\left\lVert g_n(O)\right\rVert)$$,
where $f$ is a function and $g_n$ with $n\in N$ are also functions.

Also I would like to reiterate that $ad$ is the adjoint action in  this case and not the adjoint representation

Comment: Just a quick remark: The operator $O \mapsto Ad_O$ that you mention has a kernel given by scalar diagonal matrices. You shall not expect an equality $\| Ad_O \|_1= \| O \|_2$, for two given norms, since the left hand side will be zero for those matrices and the right hand side not.

Comment: Oh that is not what I was asking. I was more interested in something of the form:
$\left\lVert ad_O\right\rVert=f(\left\lVert g_1(O)\right\rVert,...,\left\lVert g_n(O)\right\rVert)$.
Also note that I was asking for $ad$ and not $Ad$